# Open subset associated to a global section of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $U=\text{Spec}(A)$ be an open subset of a scheme $X$ and $f\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$. We define $$X_f=\{x\in X: f_x\notin \mathfrak{m}_x\subseteq \mathcal{O}_x\}.$$
Then, we have to prove that $X_f$ is open in $X$.

This is an exercise in Hartshone. It asks to prove that $X_f\cap U=D(\bar{f})$ where $\bar{f}=f|_U$.

Let $P\in U\cap X_f$ i.e., $P\in \text{Spec}$(A) and $f_P\notin \mathfrak{m}_P\subseteq \mathcal{O}_P$. I am stuck here and could not proceed.

I tried when $X=U=\text{Spec}(A)$. Then, we have isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_P\rightarrow A_P$ given by $s:U\rightarrow \bigsqcup_{q\in U} A_q$ goes to $s(P)$.  Given $f\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=A$ we have $f:U\rightarrow \bigsqcup_{q\in U} A_q$ given by $f(q)=\frac{f}{1}\in A_q$. Then, $f\in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ as per the definition of structure sheaf on $\text{Spec}(A)$. So, the isomorphism sends $[f]$ to $f(P)=\frac{f}{1}\in A_P$ i.e., $f_p\in \mathcal{O}_P$ is identified with $\frac{f}{1}\in A_P$ and $\mathfrak{m}_P$  is identified with the maximal ideal $PA_P$. So, 
$$X_f=\{P\in X: f_P\notin \mathfrak{m}_P\subseteq \mathcal{O}_P\}
=\{P\in X:\frac{f}{1}\notin PA_P\}=\{P\in X:f\notin P\}=D(f).$$

Let me know if this justification is correct. Any suggestions regarding arbitrary schemes are welcome.

Comment: Your proof for the affine case looks fine to me. In general, why not cover your scheme with open affines patches, and use your argument to prove that the intersection of $X_f$ with any of your open affines is open?

Comment: That is what I was trying to do but could not go further.. I tried to show that $U\cap X_f$ is open in $U$ when $U=\text{Spec}(A)$. @KennyWong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try and write out the logic explicitly for the general case where the scheme $X$ is covered by a collection of open affine subschemes $\{ U_i \}$ where each $U_i = {\rm Spec}(A_i)$ for some ring $A_i$.

We have natural restriction maps:
$$ \Gamma(X, \mathcal O_X) \to \Gamma(U_i, \mathcal O_X) \cong A_i.$$

Let's fix an $i$, and let's denote the image of $f$ under the above restriction map by $\bar {f_i}$, which we're thinking of as an element of the ring $A_i$. Any point $P \in U_i$ is represented by a prime ideal $\mathfrak p \subset A_i$, and the restriction of $f$ to the stalk $\mathcal O_P$ is represented by the element $$\frac{\bar {f_i}}{1} \in (A_i)_{\mathfrak p}.$$

[Remember, restricting a section to a stalk at a point is the same as restricting the section to an open subset containing the chosen point, and then restricting it further to the stalk at that point.]

By the argument you provided, the set $X_f \cap U_i$ is precisely the set $$ D(\bar{f_i}) = \{ \mathfrak p {\rm \ prime } \subset A_i : \bar{f_i} \notin \mathfrak p\},$$
which is open, by the definition of the Zariski topology. Since $X_f \cap U_i$ is open for every $U_i$ in the open cover, we may conclude that $X_f$ itself is open.

Comment: what is the reason to consider restriction of $f$ to $U_i$? How did you think about it?

Comment: @cello As we are trying to reduce the general problem to the problem about affine schemes that you already solved, and as we are restricting our attention to each open affine $U_i$ in turn, it feels quite natural to consider the restriction of $f$ to each $U_i$!

Comment: fair enough! Thank you :)